# SQL join problems - users betting on matches

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

scores:

```
user_id | match_id | points
   1    |   110    |   4
   1    |   111    |   3
   1    |   112    |   3
   2    |   111    |   2
```

Users bet on matches and depending on the result of the match they are awarded with points. Depending on how accurate the bet was you are either awarded with 0, 2, 3 or 4 points for a match.

Now I want to rank the users so that i can see who is in 1st, 2nd place etc...
The ranking order is firstly by total_points. If these are equal its ordered by the amount of times a user has scored 4 points then by the amount of times a user scored 3 points and so on.

For that i would need the following table:

```
user_id |  total_points | #_of_fours | #_of_threes | #_of_twos
   1    |       10      |      1     |       2     |     0
   2    |        2      |      0     |       0     |     1
```

But i cant figure out the join statements which would help me get it.

This is as far as i get without help:

SELECT user_id, COUNT( points ) AS #_of_fours FROM scores WHERE points = 4 GROUP BY user_id

Which results in

```
user_id | #_of_fours
    1   |      1
    2   |      0
```

Now i would have to do that for #_of_threes and twos aswell as total points and join it all together, but i cant figure out how.

BTW im using MySQL.

Any help would be really apreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mysql syntax, you can use `SUM` to count the matching rows easily;

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(points)   AS total_points,
  SUM(points=4) AS no_of_fours,
  SUM(points=3) AS no_of_threes,
  SUM(points=2) AS no_of_twos
FROM Table1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24213/2).

Comment: Holy Cow, that was fast and looks really simple, thanks alot to all of you! One question though: shouldnt it be count instead of sum, considering i dont want the sum but the amount of times someone scores 4 points

Comment: @user1259801 A bit simplified, but `COUNT` will count rows in the result, which means you'd need 4 different results to get the count for each individual column. It can be done in one query, but will be more complex. `SUM` will add up an individual column, so generating a column with 1 for each match and 0 for each non match for each result you want will allow you to sum them up in one query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  user_id
,       sum(points) as total_points
,       sum(case when points = 4 then 1 end) AS #_of_fours 
,       sum(case when points = 3 then 1 end) AS #_of_threes
,       sum(case when points = 2 then 1 end) AS #_of_twos
FROM    scores
GROUP BY 
        user_id
```

Comment: Don't forget a `SUM(points) AS total_points`, which the sample output has

Comment: Holy Cow, that was fast and looks really simple, thanks alot to all of you! Same problem here: Shouldnt it be count instead of sum for #_of_fours etc